# how to swap VM disks in azure?

Tags: linux, centos, azure, swap

I've have recreated a virtual machine in azure, when I did it azure assigned an OS disk to the VM  which is normal and obvious, and I  have a disk from my previous virtual machine.

for now I got two disks in the panel:
 - OS disk
 - Data Disk

[image: azure disks]

what I want is to delete the "current OS disk" and Set **data disk** as **OS disk**
is that possible?

Comment: Not while the VM is running!

Comment: I can turn the vm off, no problem, beside of it what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't swap the disks in a VM, but you can register the data disk as an OS disk and build a new VM while using the newly registered disk.

What you need to do is:

1. Delete the VM while keeping the disks.
2. (Optional) Create a backup copy of the data disk, use the PowerShell command **`Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy`**, more information here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/24/create-backups-of-virtual-machines-in-windows-azure-by-using-powershell.aspx.
3. Convert the data disk to an OS disk, use the PowerShell command **`Add-AzureDisk -DiskName "MyLinuxDisk" -MediaLocation "http://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.azure.com/vhds/linuxsys.vhd" -OS "Linux"`**, more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495252.aspx
4. Create a new custom VM, where you will use the newly added OS disk, you will find it under the "My Images" section in the Azure portal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the guidance I'm new to the azure world!